# Advanced animations with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to convert a site from flash to HTML/CSS/JS ( don't ask why, I just have to ) but I'm stuck about the animations that I need.

Please follow the link and look at the site: http://www.sultanahmetkoftesi.com

As you can see, the moving layers are accelerated when you move the mouse. That is exactly what I want to do.

I'd be glad if you can provide an example or snippet.

Pure Javascript or jQuery code is fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these two projects can somehow help you...
1. http://css-tricks.com/1660-jquery-robot/
2. http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at http://spritely.net/